# Spring AOP : Annotated pointcuts for a method with @Transactional annotated method?

Tags: java, spring, aspectj, spring-aop, spring-annotations

In my businesslogic methods , I have used annotations as follows for Transaction management.

```
@Service
public class SampleBusinessLogicImpl implements SampleBusinessLogic {


    @Override
    @Transactional(rollbackFor=Exception.class)
    public Sample createSample(Sample sample) throws SampleException {
             ...
        }
}
```

I wanted to execute another aspect for this method , I defined an aspect as follows :

```
@Aspect
public class SampleDynamicValidationAspect {

    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(RequestValidationAspect.class); 


    @Before("execution(public * com.rakuten.gep.sample.businesslogic.impl.SampleBusinessLogicImpl.createSample(com.rakuten.gep.sample.entity.common.Sample,..)) && args(sample,..) throws *Exception")
    public void validate(Sample sample) throws SampleException {
        //Dynamic validation here.
        //If some validation is failed, wrapped the appropiate exception in SampleException
        logger.debug("Involking Dynamic Validator");
        System.out.println("************** Dynaic Validator *************");
    }
}
```

I can see Transactions works fine looking at the logs , but this newly declared advise doesn't get executed.

Any things ?

Comment: Can you check your spring configuration & see if the aspect configured as bean? post your configuration here, as the problem could be there too.

Answer (score 1):

try to change validate(Sample) to validate(JointPoint)

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this in different ways. For example, you can find different pointcut options that you can test. Below you can find different options you can try to make your aspect work.

By executing everything matching @Transactional

```
execution(@Transactional * *.*(..))
```

By executing every public method (you can use this to test if you have your Aspect framework configured well).

```
execution(public * *(..))
```

By adding a pointcut like this and then apply it to your aspect:

```
@Pointcut("execution(@Transactional* *.*(..))")
public void monitorRequestTargets(){}

@Around("monitorRequestTargets()")
public void validate(Sample sample) throws SampleException {
```

Let me know if any of then worked ok.

Answer (score 0):

Your pointcut expression should be

```
@Before("execution(public * com.rakuten.gep.sample.businesslogic.impl.SampleBusinessLogicImpl.createSample(com.rakuten.gep.sample.entity.common.Sample,..) throws *Exception) && args(sample,..)")
```